# My if statement based on array value being empty refuses to work

Tags: php

I wrote the following script to echo out the contents of a outlook CSV File.

Here is a part of the script which breaks down the CSV into an array that extracts only the following three values, first name, last name and email.

```
for ($i=87; $i<= $countdel-87; $i=$i+88 ){

if(empty($readout[$i])){ echo "<b style=\"color:RED;\">FIRST NAME N/A</b>"; }
else{ echo str_replace("Categories","",$readout[$i]).".........................."; }

if(empty($readout[$i+2])){ echo "<b style=\"color:RED;\">LAST NAME N/A</b>".".........................."; }
else{ echo $readout[$i+2].".........................."; };

if(empty($readout[$i+14])){ echo "<b style=\"color:RED;\">EMAIL N/A</b>"; }
else{ echo $readout[$i+14]; };

echo "<br>";
}
```

The code then spits out a string that looks like this:

```
Joe ............. Smith ...............jSmith@yahoo.com
```

Now say that we do not have the last name or email, instead it will spit out

```
Joe .......... LAST NAME N/A .............. EMAIL N/A
```

This all works just dandy. Where I am having the problem is when I do not have the first name, as it prints out.

```
........... Smith ..............jSmith@yahoo.com
```

This piece of code is where the problem seems to be:

```
if(empty($readout[$i])){ echo "<b style=\"color:RED;\">FIRST NAME N/A</b>"; }
```

It appears that the `$readout[$i]` is never empty although I never see anything print out when there is no value. However all the other `$readout[$i+$foo]` arrays to work.

Comment: Double check the CSV file to make sure there isn't a blank space, " ", in the first name section.

Comment: Can you edit into your question as to what `print_r($readout)` looks like on the troublesome line? Perhaps the element containing the first name isn't in fact empty?

Comment: For readability reasons I'd advise indenting your code, and splitting your single-line `if`/`else` constructs over several lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work, what was going on was `$readout[$i]` had white space at the beginning of it causing it not to be 'empty'. In addition to that the first column of the second row of an outlook CSV cluster shares the column as the last row of the first column. So that is why I have to remove "Categories" from `$readout[$i]` FYI.

Here is how I built the new constructs into the problem if statement.

I simply use the `trim()` function to remove white space, then use `str_replace()` to remove the word 'Categories'. Finally I check the value to see if it is blank.

```
if(trim(str_replace("Categories","",$readout[$i])) == ""){ echo "<b style=\"color:RED;\">FIRST NAME N/A</b>".".........................."; }
else{ echo str_replace("Categories","",$readout[$i]).".........................."; }
```

Thank you all for your answers and suggestions.